# How to find past reCaptcha account setups?

Tags: recaptcha

I've logged into my Google account, and navigated to the reCaptcha setup page.  But all it shows is the form to create a new reCaptcha account.

I think I used to be able to find my previous accounts setup for my different domains, but there doesn't appear to be anywhere to do that now (Something like a link to 'MY reCaptcha'??).  I know I have at least 6 of them at this point.

If it is still possible, can someone give me instructions on how to access my past setups?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have accidentally found the list of my sites.

When you go to the Google reCaptcha admin console, you end up at this url: [www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create).  On this page, you can't find any link that gets you to your list of accounts.

However, if you just delete the last sub directory **create**: [www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/), you can now see a drop down list of your sites, and have the settings gear icon, which will allow you to see your reCaptcha keys for each selected site).

*Sometimes I have noticed a difference in the URL structure, with a **/u/0/** or  **/u/2/** in the middle of the URL.*  (ie: google.com/u/0/recaptcha/admin/), but it doesn't seem to make a difference in what is displayed.

**NOTE**: Of course, you must be logged in with the Google account that you used to create the reCaptcha accounts in the first place.

Comment: Life saver! I spend ages looking for this. Many thanks. Adrian